# Preview really different then the Render Version

Tags: rendering, glass

Maybe somebody can help me, my render version looks alot more different then the preview Version in the Editor.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe check the Viewport Shading panel, in case you've disabled Scene Lights and Scene World?

Comment: Could you show us the shader tree / share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . please?

Comment: I got it :D
There is a modifier on the Object and i dont know why but the view for the rendered ones was disabled.